# Ignore type errors in prolog and return false instead

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I want the prolog engine to return false instead of an error.
I have this code:

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).

set_1(X):-member(X,[f(f(1))]).
p :- X in 1..3,set_1(f(X)).
```

When I query p, I get an error:

```
?- p.
ERROR: Type error: `integer' expected, found `f(1)'
```

I want the output to look like:

```
 ?- p.
 false
```

I would expect to see false even if I change member(X,[f(f(1))]) to  member(X,[f(f(f(1)))]) , or to some other set, without making any other changes to my program.

I am using swi-prolog v 5.10.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `catch/3`. Example:

```
?- catch(p, error(type_error(_,_),_), false).
false.
```

It is declaratively perfectly OK to replace *type* errors by silent failure like this. This is not true for *instantiation* errors, since an instantiation error can turn to solutions when you add more goals, but a type error can not.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Unfortunately in certain cases the behavior of returning false in case of an error is not the expected one. Consider set_1(X):-member(X,[f(f(1)),f(1)]). The answer should be true but it returns false because there is an error in matching with the first argument. I ended up with implementing my own member function which always works.